# Подгрузка новых данных во время листания в Table/ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Имеется TableView. Надо во время приближения какой-то ячейки сверху (пускай indexPath.row = 1) запускался запрос на добавление данных в таблицу. Соответсвенно пользователь должен остаться там, где он и листал таблицу. Так происходит, например, в приложение VK, во время просмотра диалога. Вы листаете и видите как бегунок сам спускается ниже.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if ((indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 1)) 
    {
        [self loadMore];
    }
}
```

Вот тут я запускаю метод на обновление.
Далее запускает обращение к серверу. По ответу на которое я делают следующее:

```
CGFloat initialOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
[self.tableView reloadData];

[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:items.count inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

CGPoint afterContentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
CGPoint newContentOffset = CGPointMake(afterContentOffset.x, afterContentOffset.y + initialOffset);
self.tableView.contentOffset = newContentOffset;
```

Где items - пришедшие новые элементы для отображения в таблице.

И работает почти как надо, но подгрузка стопорит пользователя. Это происходит не плавно.

Знает кто-то как сделать так же как диалоги в ВК работают?

Т.е. нужна именно плавность работы.

Comment: Я так понимаю что загрузка идет в основном потоке и поэтому пидторможуе, почитай о GCD.

Comment: Нет, подгрузка идёт в блоке, который запускается по ответу от сервера.
Подтормаживание связано с тем, что приходится запускать scrollToIndexPath и изменять contentOffset таким образом. Для пользователя это выливает в остановку его листания.

Answer (score 1):

Если используется версия iOS 10+, то есть замечательная вещь, которая прогружает ячейки заранее - prefetching. Подробнее можно прочесть [здесь](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching).

Так же, если использование prefetching почему-то невозможно - то, заполняйте ячейку асинхронно, через dispatch_async например. Такой подход так же можно увидеть в Вконтакте, когда изображение в ленте подгружается позже.